# Would we qualify for StackExchange Community Ads?

Tags: feature-request

Does StackExchange still allow [Community Ads](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) and if so, do public beta sites like ours count?

**Update**: Glenn points out other Beta Meta sites learned this was for graduated sites only. I'll leave this as a feature request then.

Examples we'd use Community Ads for:

- Open Source Projects
- Community Webinar Announcements
- User Group Meetings
- Community Contests

Answer (score 2):

The following (somewhat old) meta posts on other SE sites would seem to indicate this is a feature for graduated sites only:

1. [Provide a non-system-message channel for moderators to contact all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115729/provide-a-non-system-message-channel-for-moderators-to-contact-all-users/116286#116286)
2. https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/promoting-travel-se-activities-community-ads
3. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/546/please-enable-community-promotion-ads-here

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't searching hard enough (the other beta sites). The Meta Travel mentions some nice points that we can try (thematic weeks and event chats for example).